# send_keys to hidden elements

Tags: python, selenium, hidden, sendkeys

I want to send a text to a text box of a page.

Here is hidden element on page:

```
<textarea class="chatterTopicsEnabled groupAtMentionsEnabled publishertextarea" 
  id="publishereditablearea" 
  name="publishereditablearea" 
  role="textbox" tabindex="0" 
  title="Topics" type="text" wrap="soft" 
  data-uidsfdc="112" style="height: 208px;">Topics</textarea>
<input type="hidden" id="publisherprompttext" name="publisherprompttext" value="Topics">
```

My code by which i can click the text box but can do nothing to send text:

```
textbox = [tag for tag in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('textarea') 
           if tag.get_attribute('name') == 'publishereditablearea']
textbox[0].click()
textbox[0].send_keys("text")
```

The error message said: `element not visible.`

How can I send a text to the textbox?

Comment: Did you try to find by ID `publishereditablearea`? What operation goes wrong, `click` or `send_keys`?

Comment: selenium doesn't interact with hidden element. you application should enable that element to interact. are you able to do it manually?

Comment: You could use JavaScript. But it might not be a good idea to do so in a testing context. There should be a good reason, why this element is hidden and executing a test case which is not doing what a real user could do is questionable.

Comment: Was my answer useful? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Comment: @Rloqvist, yes, i have tried ID and xpath, but it does not work.

Comment: @Murthi, i am tring and looking for reference to do it

Comment: @Würgspaß, Thank you.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov, Thank you, I will try your solution and give my feedback

Answer (score 2):

Use like this using `execute_script` as your element is hidden

```
element=driver.find_element_by_id("publishereditablearea") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: Thank you, after click action, how to send value to the text box?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (it must work):

```
js = "document.getElementById('publishereditablearea').value = 'text';"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

Comment: hi, i have tried this code on my end, but it does not work well. The text has not been inserted into text box.

Comment: @YamPakChing, any other error message? Because it's working for me.

Comment: There is no error for this code, but no output came from this code. and i have added new code of html. i am sure i could click the text box but do nothing for sending text

Comment: @YamPakChing, after my code you need to save your results. Is this not working?

Comment: @YamPakChing, also you can try like this: `js = "document.getElementById('publishereditablearea').innerHTML = 'text';"`. Let me know about results.