# Hidden input Selenium Python in Div within TD

Tags: python, html, selenium

**Background**

I am trying to automate a website data input; however, I have not found a way to send the value to the field "___33_xsde_6h_input__data" for the portion of the HTML attached.

I have seen that Selenium is unable to write directly to hidden fields per [the question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079040/selenium-python-how-to-insert-value-on-a-hidden-input), [the question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53388823/clicking-the-hidden-input-selenium-in-python), [question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434202/send-keys-to-hidden-elements) and [question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049182/write-value-to-hidden-element-with-selenium-python-script). However I have not been able to find the specific solution for my scenario.

**Code Attempted**

***HTML***

```
<td class="RND_Input" colspan="1"><div id="RND_generatedId_1" class="RND_FieldDecor">
<div class="RND_MII_Container">
<input type="hidden" name="___33_xsde_6h_input__data" value="RND:null-axxx"><input id="___33_xsde_6h_input__data" class="" type="text" 
value="[not defined]" autocomplete="off">
</div></div></td>
```

***Python:***

I have tried most of the solutions to see if the element is being able to be set, without luck

```
#Attempt 1 by Xpath
inputElement =ObjSelenium.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="___33_xsde_6h_input__data"]')
inputElement =ObjSelenium.find_element(By.XPATH,'.//input[@id="___33_xsde_6h_input__data"]'
    '/following-sibling::input[@type="hidden"]')
#Attempt 2 by CSS_SELECTOR 
inputElement=ObjSelenium.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.RND_Input>input[type=hidden]') 
inputElement=ObjSelenium.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.RND_MII_Container>input[type=hidden]')
#Attempt 3 by ID
js = "document.getElementById('___33_xsde_6h_input__data').value = 'text';"
ObjSelenium.execute_script(js)
```

**Question**

How can I be able to set the HTML element ""___33_xsde_6h_input__data"" within Selenium driver in order to update its value?

**Edit:**
The answer from Undetectable Selenium threw the following (with both approaches)

```
TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0039FDC3+2555331]
    Ordinal0 [0x003377F1+2127857]
    Ordinal0 [0x00232E08+1060360]
    Ordinal0 [0x0025E49E+1238174]
    Ordinal0 [0x0025E69B+1238683]
    Ordinal0 [0x00289252+1413714]
    Ordinal0 [0x00277B54+1342292]
    Ordinal0 [0x002875FA+1406458]
    Ordinal0 [0x00277976+1341814]
    Ordinal0 [0x002536B6+1193654]
    Ordinal0 [0x00254546+1197382]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00539622+1619522]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x005E882C+2336844]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x004323E1+541697]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00431443+537699]
    Ordinal0 [0x0033D18E+2150798]
    Ordinal0 [0x00341518+2168088]
    Ordinal0 [0x00341660+2168416]
    Ordinal0 [0x0034B330+2208560]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76026359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B087A4+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B08774+180]
```

Comment: HTML is incomplete. It still needs a `</div>`

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Thank you, I assumed it was one of the leftovers but I just realized my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.RND_Input input[id*='input'][id$='data']"))).send_keys("Sgdva")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='RND_Input']//input[contains(@id, 'input') and contains(@id, 'data')]"))).send_keys("Sgdva")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you! However I am running into issues using both methods, my question is updated

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

The thing is that the code was in another frame, I realized it when I tried to update my HTML and realized there were 2 body tags.

So in order to activate the correct Xpath, I needed to activate the frame [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898340/python-selenium-cant-find-iframe-xpath)

```
ObjSelenium.switch_to.frame(ObjSelenium.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='RND _SubSessioniFrame']")) 
#where RND_SubSessioniFrame is the name of the iframe element associated in the main HTML
inputElement =ObjSelenium.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="___33_xsde_6h_input__data"]')
inputElement.send_keys("Yay!")
```

As noticed, I do not set Wait elements here because I did so before going to the previous step with the following.

```
WebDriverWait(ObjSelenium, 10).until(ObjSeleniumExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ButtonShowedAfterLoad"]')))
```